# Selecionar opção select

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, excel-vba

Caros,

estou tentando selecionar uma opção em um select com o seguinte código e não estou conseguindo encontrar uma solução.

Consigo localizar o elemento, mas não informar para ele selecionar X opção.

Estou localizando com o seguinte código:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@data-ng-model='passoUmCtrl.model.protocoloAtivo.relacionamento']")
```

Como posso selecionar uma opção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caros,

Resolvido com o seguinte código:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@data-ng-model='passoUmCtrl.model.protocoloAtivo.relacionamento']").AsSelect.selectByValue (1)
```